# Clustering validation based on features distribution within each cluster

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

Are there any methods for clustering validation based on features distribution within each cluster?
The question is inspired by [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/elbow-method-is-not-sufficient-to-find-best-k-in-k-means-clustering-fc820da0631d) , where the author says at the end:

> I also validate the output clusters by indexing/checking the distribution of the input features within the clusters.

but, unfortunatelly, does not elaborate more.

Just an example I can think of. After performing an unsupervised clustering, check the averages of features for the samples inside one cluster and prove that the difference between the averages of another cluster is statistically significant.

Does it make sence? Could you please advise the materials on this topic, if any? Maybe I am wrong with my search query, but Google does not give me anything.